# how to export modules and variables

Tags: javascript, node.js

Im working on sensor code and when an object is it certain bounds it should emit('enterProximity') 
so when this code runs

main.js

```
var entered = require('./main').onProximityBoolean
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
setInterval(function() {
console.log("entered index " + entered);
var here = entered.onProximityBoolean;
if (here == true) {
  socket.emit('enterProximity');
} 
 },1000);
 }
```

In this code "here" should equal true when "enter" is true in main.js

```
enter = false
function onProximityBoolean(enter) {
      console.log(enter + " emit entered");
      return enter;
}

module.exports = {
  withinBounds: withinBounds,
  onProximityBoolean: onProximityBoolean(enter)
};
```

but instead it prints like this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yvh6U.jpg

how do i get here to reassign itself continously?

Comment: You are calling the function `onProximityBoolean` in module.exports with `enter` which from the code posted is `undefined`.
Which assigns the key `onProximityBoolean` with a value false and it never changes.

Comment: i forgot to add that i had defined it, i edited it thanks

Comment: Even with the update. the variable `enter` is never changing as you are not calling `onProximityBoolean` inside `setInterval`.
Further More, since `module.exports = {
  withinBounds: withinBounds,
  onProximityBoolean: onProximityBoolean(enter)
};` has an assigned value `false` for  the key `onProximityBoolean`

Answer (score 1):

Your module.exports is returning the value of onProximityBoolean(undefined), rather than the *function* itself.

If you change your module.exports to this

```
module.exports = {
  withinBounds: withinBounds,
  onProximityBoolean: onProximityBoolean,
};
```

and then your runner to this:

```
var entered = require('./main').onProximityBoolean
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  setInterval(function() {
    console.log("entered index " + entered);
    var here = entered.onProximityBoolean(entered);
    if (here == true) {
      socket.emit('enterProximity');
    } 
  },1000);
}
```

does that fix your issue? The change is to make sure that onProximityBoolean is a function, and that you call the function every time in your setInterval loop.